Ignoring current spikes
I have a circuit which measures a current draw going to System A, waits for it to rise from 0.24A to 0.26A, then has a 30s delay before supplying power to System B. If the current drops below the threshold, power to System B gets cut off immediately. The problem is that System A sometimes spikes up close enough to the threshold to trigger the 30s delay, so System B is powered preemptively. Can anyone help me figure out a way to ignore these current spikes?  Circuit overview: I have a 0.9ohm current sensing resistor, Rsense. The voltage across that resistor goes into a 10x gain op-amp (LM2904) circuit, outputting under 2.4V at 0.24A pull and over 2.4V at 0.26 pull. The MCP65R41 comparator uses an internal Vref of 2.4V, so it outputs 3.3V when the LM2904 outputs above 2.4V. The MCP65 output goes a few places: the 1A input of the monostable multivibrator (CD74HC), through an RC delay circuit and into the 2B input of the CD74, and the D input of the flip-flop (TC7W74). The 2Qbar and 1Qbar route to the CLK input of the flip-flop. Basically, when the MCP65 output goes from low to high, the 2Qbar output goes low for 30s and then high again, triggering the flip-flop to accept the D input and output 3.3V. When it goes from high to low, the 1Qbar goes low for a couple hundred nanoseconds and then back high, triggering the flip-flop to output low. The RC delay on the 2B line - on the order of milliseconds - prevents it from triggering and holding the CLK line low until the 1Qbar output has already gone high again. From there it's just an NMOS-PMOS setup to use the flip-flop output to control 24V to System B. Problem overview: System A sometimes has current spikes up to around 0.25A before it truly jumps to 0.26A. I'm working on getting an oscilloscope capture of said spikes, but observing the power supply I can assume that they're in the range of a couple hundred milliseconds. 0.25A draw puts the LM2904 output at ~2.38 V, which is apparently close enough to 2.4V to put the MCP65 in a weird state where it outputs ~2V, which triggers the multivibrator. So my question is, assuming the current spikes are a couple hundred milliseconds, how can I ignore them? Low-pass filter? Increase the op-amp gain to set the current threshold more precisely? (Problem there is System A can draw more current after it boots up, and I don't want the op-amp outputting super high voltages) I'm a little lost and would appreciate any input.  For full clarity, System A is a motor controller hub and System B is the brakes for said motors. System A jumps to 0.26A current draw when the first motor enables, and I want to wait 30s to ensure all motors enable before I disengage the brakes. Hence why it would be bad for a current spike to trigger the circuit, and the first motor to enable 28s later - I would disengage the brakes 2s later before other motors enable and things would... crash. Expensively.


Also sorry for the hand-drawn circuit, I had it handy already. I'll add a digital one if I can get to it today.

How does your diagram relate to system A or B (whatever they might be)?

@Andyaka VA (top right) is the connection to System A, VB (bottom right) is to System B.

A few things: assuming the LM2904 and MCP65 are powered from the same rail, you don't need to worry about the amplified current sense signal getting too high. Edit: since they are powered from separate rails, either using a higher-voltage comparator and voltage dividing the output down to logic level or adding e.g. a Zener to the input of the comparator would be prudent.
Some RC filtering on the input of the LM2904/sense resistor could fix the situation. You would also probably want to add some hysteresis to the comparator, either with a network on the output or a new device with internal hysteresis. It won't fix the problem you're seeing but the ramp rate will now be even slower and you don't want a bunch of spurious transitions.
Also obligatory observation: you could replace everything from the MCP65 to the flip flop with a microprocessor in a SOT-23-6 for less than $1 and call it a day.
10k gate resistors seems like there might be switching-time power dissipation related problems with your main pass element.
If the motor-brake interaction could possibly lead to an expensive problem, then some sort of interlock circuit wouldn't be a bad idea.

Ugh I would love to but circuit is required to be pure analog, out of my hands. LM2904 is +24V powered. I'll think about an RC filter on the sense input. Thanks for your input!

We do have a safety layer that will hopefully be able to step in for motor problems, but would prefer that to be the redundancy layer.  I'll double check the power dissipation values but so far the circuit has been functioning in that regard.
